# Defining a variable taking on multiple values

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to define some kind of local variable that takes on a list of values, so that I can reference that list in a query. I have a field, "my_field", and I want to write a query that returns 1 when "my_field" takes on a value of 'term1', 'term2', or 'term3', and returns 0 when it takes on any other value.

Here's what I've attempted:

```
DEFINE my_variable IN ('term1', 'term2', 'term3');

SELECT
   CASE WHEN my_field IN '&my_variable' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'new_field'
FROM my_table
```

This doesn't work though, I get syntax errors. I'm using Oracle's SQLDeveloper. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What syntax errors do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a few issues off-hand.

- you are missing an equals sign when defining your variable;
- your substitution variable reference should not be in single quotes;
- you are repeating the `IN` keyword;
- the column expression alias should also not be in single quotes.

```
DEFINE my_variable = IN ('term1', 'term2', 'term3')

SELECT
   CASE WHEN my_field &my_variable THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS new_field
FROM my_table
```

Running that with `set verify on` shows the final, valid, query it generates:

```
old:SELECT
   CASE WHEN my_field &my_variable THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS new_field
FROM my_table
new:SELECT
   CASE WHEN my_field IN ('term1', 'term2', 'term3') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS new_field
FROM my_table

 NEW_FIELD
----------
         1
```

---

> I have many terms that I am putting into the variable, and I am adding line breaks to help keep the code clean. However, when I do this, it causes the query to error.

If you want to split the `define` into multiple lines you can use the `-` continuation character, but in SQL Developer you need to actually make it a comment for it to work properly:

```
DEFINE my_variable = IN ( --
  'term1', --
  'term2', --
  'term3')

SELECT
   CASE WHEN my_field &my_variable THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS new_field
FROM my_table
/
```

which `set verify on` shows as:

```
old:SELECT
   CASE WHEN my_field &my_variable THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS new_field
FROM my_table

new:SELECT
   CASE WHEN my_field IN ( --
  'term1', --
  'term2', --
  'term3') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS new_field
FROM my_table

 NEW_FIELD
----------
         1
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this unfortunately did not work. I'm getting the error "invalid relational operator"

Comment: Did you add the missing equals sign; and are you running as a script or as a statement? I've run exactly as shown (as a script) and shown the result I got. To get that error I think you would have to either run as a script with a malformed define (which errors), or run as a statement; and either way not enter anything when promoted for the substitution value?

Comment: It's also possible you've changed the define character, or done `set define off`. Run `show define` in that session and check what it says. You may need to turn it back on and/or set to ampersand.

Comment: Okay I've nearly got it working with your solution, there's just one thing that's breaking. When I run your code from your original answer, it works. However, I have many terms that I am putting into the variable, and I am adding line breaks to help keep the code clean. However, when I do this, it causes the query to error. Any idea how I can use your solution with line breaks separating the terms?

Comment: @NathanCalverley - I've added a version with line breaks, hopefully that is what you meant.

Comment: Ok this is so close to working. It works with just one variable, but now I've added a second variable, and it's breaking again. The error I'm getting is "Unknown command: symbol myvar2 is undefined", where 'myvar2' is the name of my second variable. I'm defining it in exactly the same way as the original variable. Any ideas?